# Why does hexadecimal floating point need to have a specified exponent?

Tags: c, standards

I'm learning about programming languages now (BNFs, scanners, etc) and it seems weird that hexadecimal floating point constants in C require an exponent.

From the C99 standard,

§6.4.4.2 Floating constants

```
hexadecimal-floating-constant:  
    hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-fractional-constant  
        binary-exponent-part floating-suffix[opt]  
    hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit-sequence  
        binary-exponent-part floating-suffix[opt]
```

It seems easy to write a scanner that will parse hexadecimal floating point constants with an optional exponent. Why does the C standard make the exponent optional for decimal floating points and required for hex floating points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is covered in the [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), section 6.4.4.2:

> *A new feature of C99:* C99 adds hexadecimal notation because it more
>   clearly expresses the  significance of floating constants. The
>   binary-exponent part is required, instead of optional as it  is for
>   decimal notation, to avoid ambiguity resulting from an **`f`** suffix being
>   mistaken as a  hexadecimal digit.

For example, `1.0f` is a decimal floating-point constant of type `float`, but `0x1.0f` would be ambiguous, and must be written as `0x1.0p0f`.

For the same reason, the exponent is introduced by `p` rather than `e` because `e` is a valid hexadecimal digit.